# Перевести в верхний регистр первую букву каждого слова

Tags: ассемблер

Есть некая строка, например: `"Assembler language programming is the fastest in the world"`. Задача сделать каждую букву нового слова заглавной. Есть код-макет для немного другого примера(там просто удалить первое слово) и не могу понять как реализовать, у меня была идея с циклом, но я не придумал как выделять слова, т.к. количество символов в каждом слове разная. Может у вас есть какие-то идеи?
Код-макет:

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
Original_string db 'Assembler language programming is the fastest in the world.', 13, 10, '$' 
Formed_line db 255 DUP(?) 
.code
.386
main:
mov ax, @data
mov ds,ax 
mov es,ax
; ========= Вывод начальной строки. ============
mov dx, offset Original_string
mov ah, 9
int 21h
; ===============================
cld 
mov ecx, LENGTHOF Original_string 
sub ecx, 10
mov esi, [OFFSET Original_string]+10 ; Зададим адресс источника + длина строки 'Assembler'
mov edi, OFFSET Formed_line ; Зададим адрес получателя данных
rep movsb ; Сформируем нужную строку
; ====== Вывод сформированной строки. ============
mov dx, offset Formed_line
mov ah, 9
int 21h
; ===============================
mov ax, 4C00h ; Номер функции DOS:4C00h закончить программу в АХ
int 21h ; Вызов функции DOS из АХ
end main
```

Comment: Если предыдущий символ равен разделителю(пробел/табуляция/точка/запятая/.....) или это первый символ - вот таким условием в цикле находят начало слова в любом ЯП.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В таблице ASCII, разница между заглавной и прописной буквой ровно `20h`. Тогда получается, что отличаются они всего одним битом(6), т.к. `0x20=00100000b`. Если прочитать символ и взвести `OR` в нём указанный бит(6), то получим прописную букву, а если сбросить `AND` - заглавную. Допустим "маркером окончания строки" является символ точки(.), соответственно код будет выглядеть примерно так (fasm x32):

```
format   pe gui
include 'win32ax.inc'
;//----------
.code
start:  invoke MessageBox,0,szStr,0,0  ;// покажем исходную строку

        mov    esi,szStr        ;// указатель на неё
        mov    ah,11011111b     ;// маска = 20h
        and    byte[esi],ah     ;// делаем первый символ строки заглавным
@@:     lodsb                   ;// берём в AL очередной..
        cmp    al,'.'           ;// конец строки?
        je     @stop            ;// да - на выход.
        cmp    al,' '           ;// это пробел? (новое слово)
        jne    @begin           ;// нет - пропустить.
        and    byte[esi],ah     ;// иначе: сбросить бит(6) - заглавная буква.
@begin: jmp    @b               ;// промотать цикл, пока не встретим точку(.)

@stop:  invoke MessageBox,0,szStr,0,0  ;// покажем результат
        invoke  ExitProcess,0
.end start
;//----------
.data
szStr   db  'Assembler language programming is the fastest in the world.',0
```

Comment: На редкость простой и понятный код, люблю такое. Даже не зная толком ассемблер всё можно понять )

Answer (score 1):

Если заглянем в таблицу символов ASCII, то увидим там две группы букв: `'A'..'Z'` и `'a'..'z'` - они следуют по возрастанию их кодов именно в таком порядке. Любой другой символ вне этих групп можем считать символом-разделителем слов. Соответственно, букву можем считать первой в слове, если предыдущий символ является разделителем. Для этого нужна переменная, в которой будем сохранять статус очередного выводимого символа: 0 - если разделитель, 1 - если буква. И при считывании очередной маленькой буквы будем проверять эту переменную: если равна 0, значит буква первая в слове - превращаем её в большую, просто добавив `'A'-'a'`.

В общем, приведу вариант цикла преобразования без проверки переполнения буфера (т.е., копирование будет происходить до тех пор, пока не встретится символ `'$'`). Указатель на исходную строку - `DS:SI`, указатель на буфер с результирующей строкой - `ES:DI` (может совпадать и исходной строкой). Код не отлаживал, так что могут быть косяки))

```
mov     ah,'$'      ;в AH - символ конца строки
mov     cx,1        ;в CX - просто 1
xor     dx,dx       ;предыдущий символ: 0 - разделитель, 1 - буква
jmp     LoadChar    ;переходим к циклу

;записываем разделитель
StoreDelim:
xor     dx,dx       ;помечаем как разделитель
stosb               ;записываем в новую строку
jmp     LoadChar    ;переходим к следующему циклу

;записываем букву
StoreLetter:
mov     dx,cx       ;помечаем как букву
StoreChar:    
stosb               ;записываем в новую строку   
                    ;(переходим к следующему циклу)
LoadChar:
lodsb               ;считываем очередной символ
cmp     al,ah       ;конец строки?
je      StoreEOL    ;да: выход из цикла

;далее проверяем символ, и прыгаем на 
;соответствующую ветку для буквы или разделителя
cmp     al,'A'
jb      StoreDelim  ;если меньше 'A', то записываем разделитель
cmp     al,'Z'
jbe     StoreLetter ;если ,больше или равно 'A' и меньше или равно 'Z', то то записываем букву (большая)
cmp     al,'a'
jb      StoreDelim  ;если меньше 'a', то записываем разделитель
cmp     al,'z'
ja      StoreDelim  ;если больше 'z', то записываем разделитель...

;...иначе: очередной символ - маленькая буква
test    dx,dx       ;предыдущий символ - разделитель?
jnz     StoreChar   ;нет: выводим букву как есть
add     al,'A'-'a'  ;да: преобразуем букву в большую...
jmp     StoreLetter ;...и выводим её (с пометкой в DX)

;записываем символ конца строки и выходим из цикла
StoreEOL:
stosb

;.............
;код дальше...
```